# I made a contract with 1 eth from a tutorial and I want to know if I lost it or can I recover it

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

could someone help me identify if I was scammed or not, please follow the following video link `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwpCxLGTl20`
I did exactly the indicated steps and I did not have any profit, I don't even see the 1 eth that I invested in the contract, I want to know if I lost it or can I recover it

the code: `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVdFCJdUNUsmSnEwZvT9HgNeteYEshCVZcGayVqtqWWmd`

my contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x41e9db6560d1100aDc63c5D051bAa8957a2F0B94

thank you

Comment: You have deployed a scam contract, you won't be able to recover the ether deposited.

Comment: Could you explain to me at least briefly how you realized that the contract is fraudulent?

Comment: Every week there 2 or 3 people asking the same question: They deployed a contract after watching a YT video, and they can't get their money back. There are slight variations of the contract but it is mostly the same.